# Umbraco LiveDll referencing from Separate Controller Project

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I've enabled `LiveDll` for my `Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.ModelsMode` in `web.config` to get strongly typed models. As you may or may not know, this generates a dll on disk named `Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels` in the `bin` folder of the Umbraco web site.

My problem is that I don't understand how to get a "clean" reference from my (separate) controllers project. (I don't particularly enjoy the prospect of referencing the models dll "as is" in the web site `bin` folder.)

Anyone know how this is supposed to be set up?

Comment: Set it as AppData and render the models. After that copy them to a seperated project and then reference them to your controller project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you reference the Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.dll 
from your controllers project then you will cause a circular reference so that won't work.

The way we have it working is by setting the ModelsBuilder to Dll

```
<add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.ModelsMode" value="Dll" />
```

We have then set a `Library` folder and copied the dll to that folder. The other project then references the dll in the Library so we don't get a circular reference.

So our project structure is something like

```
MySolution
   UmbracoWebProject
   ControllersProject
   Library
```

We don't want to copy the dll to the Library every time we run the modelsbuilder so we created a Pre-Build event to copy the dll for us on every build.

To create the Pre-Build event right click the Umbraco Project in Visual Studio and choose Properties.  Select Build Events and add the following to Pre-Build assuming your project structure is as above.

```
IF EXIST "$(ProjectDir)bin\Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.dll" xcopy "$(ProjectDir)bin\Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.dll" "$(SolutionDir)Library"  /y
```

Using Dll mode, you will have to explicitly run the models builder from Umbraco whenever you change your DocTypes

This works well for us but it does feel as though it is an area which still needs to be thought about a little more by Umbraco and the community.  It would be nice to have an 'install and forget' solution for this.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Maybe I'm not thinking straight, but I can't see the circular reference happening - the `PublishedContentModels.dll` would be unaware of my controllers library, would it not? Anyway, what you're suggesting is close to what I imagined myself. It's a pity "pre-build" seems to be the only option available.

Comment: I guess the circular ref might kick in when you start to try and use your Umbraco generated models in your controllers... it'll almost definitely bite you at some point :)